# jquery snytax error?

Tags: jquery

I'm writing a simple function to adjust opacity, and margins on hover. Using add class.
Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here please.
Thanks alot!

http://jsfiddle.net/aDJma/3/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.connectsocialitem').each(function() {
        $(this).hover(function() {
            $(this).addClass("active")
            $('.active > a').animate({ opacity: 0.6 }, 300);
            $('.active > a').animate({marginTop:'-5px'}, 150);
        }, function() {
            $(this).removeClass("active")
            $('.active > a').animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, 150);
            $('.active > a').animate({marginTop:'0px'}, 150);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Well it's not a syntax error, I can tell you that much. You might also want to update your fiddle to use jQuery instead of Mootools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS has a text-indent of -2000 on the anchors you're animating so you'll never see the animation (the anchor is very far left of what you see). You need to animate the div that you're hovering over, or leave the anchor at a normal position and style it so it animates properly.

I've updated [your jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aDJma/36/) with an example of just animating the div itself (it's a bit slow because I didn't do any optimizing, so you'll probably want to change up the animation chaining a bit).

Comment: thanks, I got it sorted too, I just can't answer my own question.
I appreciate you taking the time. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/aDJma/20/